# Convert a private key to a .pem file

Tags: private-key, keystore, aws, kms

How can I convert a private key to a `.pem` file to upload it to AWS KMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a private key to a `.pem. file using JavaScript, you can run the following code:

```
var KeyEncoder = require('key-encoder');
var keyEncoder = new KeyEncoder.default('secp256k1');

var pemPrivateKey = keyEncoder.encodePrivate('INSERT PK WITH NO 0x', 'raw', 'pem')

console.log(pemPrivateKey);
```

You will get an output like the following:

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIKd6bjh+WOgQ9TUE0XkECHYyKXkZtrQiNtW4hDJEGOHWoAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAEp5N4bNS/NYG+V8RG0RttDVu6aWF/YWbdhGx2jTprrf5/+U0M+nutFGhP
n8HFBB2rvavHhj1hsOyamlq4U/hmrw==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert a private key to a .pem file, you can use OpenSSL, a powerful toolkit for the Transport Layer Security (TLS) and Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) protocols.

The command is
openssl rsa -in private.key -outform PEM -out private.pem,
replacing private.key with your private key file.

However, AWS Key Management Service (KMS) does not support importing of private keys. Instead, you can create a new key pair directly in AWS or import public keys.

Comment: AWS KMS supports importing of private keys. You can find how to do it here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/import-ethereum-private-keys-to-aws-kms/